Is there a way to convert a sound to a bunch vanilla minecraft sounds?
So basically, I'm asking for a tool/app, which allows us to convert any sound (.ogg/.mp3/you name it) to a bunch of vanilla Minecraft sounds, which can be later played in-game using several /playsound commands in a datapack, without needing a resoucepack for it to work.

This might be off-topic as software recommendation. Technically on-topic at SoftwareRecSE, but unlikely to get an answer there, too niche. I guess a valid answer here could be code that converts the sound, pasted into the answer, but that would be a lot of effort.

This doesn't seem possible, or at least not with any existing tool.
